# Jade multiple template files

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm really new to Node and am playing around with Express and Jade, the tutorial I'm following is out of date and I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

In my app.js file I've declared the following route:

```
app.get('/helloworld', function(req,res) {
    res.render('tasks/helloworld.jade', { title: 'Hello World!' });
});
```

So for my views I have the following

**layout.jade**

```
doctype 5
html
 head
  title= title
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css')
 body
  section.container!= body
```

Attempting to use bootstrap css

and then **tasks/helloworld.jade**

```
extends ../layout

body
 h1 Hello World
```

However, this doesn't seem to yield the result I'm thinking it should. If I remove `extends ../layout` the template renders but without any header. If I leave it in I get an error that says `body is not defined`

Any idea how to get that to render properly?

Comment: Drop the `.jade` in your `res.render('tasks/helloworld'...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jade you use blocks to extend templates. Try this:

layout.jade:

```
doctype 5
html
 head
  title= title
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css')
 body
   section.container
      block content
```

helloworld.jade:

```
extends ../layout

block content
 h1 Hello World
```

This will effectively replace whatever's in the `block content` of your layout with the new content provided, in this case `h1 Hello World`.

Edit: I added a `section.container` into the layout because I realized afterwards that I think you are trying to wrap everything inside the body. If that's not what you're trying to do you can remove that line, but make sure you fix the indenting if you do because jade cares about that.

Comment: I've tried putting put `block` lines with header and footer but they don't show up...any idea why?